# Python XLWT sometimes saves file of 0 bytes size

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwt

I have a simple function

```py
def put_to_xls(*args)
```

which works on Raspberry and it should take some data from *args  and save it to *.xls-file then. In 99% of time it works well, but sometimes is saves a file with a right name but with a size of 0 bytes. Maybe it happens because sometimes Raspberry can turn off due to power loss. Maybe something wrong with my code. But what I don't understand is how is it possible? Why I can get the file of 0 byte size, though it has a name? And how to fix it?

```
def make_worksheet(date, shift, wb):
    ws = wb.add_sheet(f'Date {date} shift {shift}')
    return ws


def make_xls(date, shift):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = make_worksheet(date=date, shift=shift, wb=wb)
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True
    headers = ['N', 'Date', 'Start',
               'Finish', 'Duration']
    for cols, header in enumerate(headers):
        ws.write(0, cols, header, font_style)
    rows_num = 1
    return wb, ws, rows_num


def save_file(date, shift, wb):
    wb.save(os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR, f'reports/{date}-{EQUIP_NAME}-{shift}.xls'))


def put_to_xls(date, shift, operations):
    wb, ws, rows_num = make_xls(date=date, shift=shift)
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    for operation in operations:
        op_date, start, finish = operation
        delta = op_length(start, finish)
        hours, minutes, seconds = timedelta_to_hms(delta)
        data = [rows_num, op_date, start[11:19], finish[11:19],
                f'{hours} h, {minutes} min, {seconds} sec.']
        for cols, header in enumerate(data):
            ws.write(rows_num, cols, header, font_style)
            ws.col(cols).width = (256 * 12) if cols == 0 else (256 * 28)
        rows_num += 1
    save_file(date=date, shift=shift, wb=wb)
    return date, shift
```

Comment: You can have a file of zero bytes because the file is created and given a name when you open it for output but data will only be physically written to it when the operating system buffer is flushed, or the file is closed. If the program fails before that, you will get a zero length file.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also think that this happens when the microcomputer turns off while writing to a file. Maybe there are some best practices on how to hedge against such a situation?

Comment: You could try calling `ws.flush_row_data()`  at regular intervals. Be warned though: as I understand it, flushing is done to a temporary file and is this is only copied to the named target file when you close it. The other alternative would be to close and reopen the file at intervals. That would of course mean that your program would have to know enough about where it was in the data to restart the output in the middle.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment is very helpful. I didn't know that the file with the name appears in the system even before the data was written to it and saved. Now I have some ideas how to do the checks